# npm install is not adding all dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I issue `npm install protractor`.

Under `/path/to/node_modules/protractor/node_modules`, i was expecting all the internal dependencies of `protractor` npm. But i am seeing only one module, `q`.

However in `/path/to/node_modules/protractor/package.json`, i can see all dependencies of protractor listed as,

```
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "0.4.4",
    "glob": "~3.2",
    "jasmine": "2.3.2",
    "jasminewd2": "0.0.6",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    ...................
}
```

Protractor module is versioned  `"3.0.0"` and npm is versioned `3.3.12`, node.js is versioned `v5.1.0`.

What has changed in these new versions? Since, all npm modules used to maintain their own dependency copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm 3 flattens the dependency tree, so you should see `protractor`'s dependencies in `/path/to/node_modules`.

If you don't see them there, my first guess is that you might have an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file that is preventing modules from being installed, so you could check for that.