# NPM Install does not install all the packages in my ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, node-modules, npm-install

I tried to install node modules with npm install. but only few packages install, not all. can someone have idea about this? thank you!

Please check my package.json file sample as follows, none of these dependencies installs.

[image]

and my node modules folder looks as follows,

[image]

My package json full code is as follows,

```js
{
  "name": "Quick",
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "version": "1.3",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.26",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.9.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.803.26",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.26",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: show what you have tried and the errors / problems you getting wrt code

Comment: May be in your project dependecies , those weren't mentioned

Comment: @SandrinJoy i have edited the question with screen shots. please have a look

Comment: put the package.json code here. Code is better than screenshot

Comment: updated with package.json code

Comment: is the devdependencies werent installed?

Comment: nothing other than few node modules as in screen shot of my node modules folder. i have to install them separately, even if i have listed in package.json file.

Comment: Did you try with yarn once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install is not adding all dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439079/npm-install-is-not-adding-all-dependencies)

Comment: @Piyush nope, until this app is released, npm install and everything worked well. but when i try to do some updates after the release, this issue started to occur. so i need to clarify , why it is not working with NPM install now.

Comment: no @SandrinJoy no luck.

Comment: is there a git repo for this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `node_modules` folder, and then in terminal do :

```
npm install --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
```

I tried with your package.json and iy worked for me.

[image: nodemodules]